# Parse Concatenated Json String In c#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

Say I Have a model like this :

```
 public class MainStruct
    {
        public Packet_Type packettype { get; set; }    
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string requestid { get; set; }
        public object packet { get; set; }
    }
```

My Clients send this model in json to server and i parse this and go on ... 
My problem is some times the send speed goes up and i get a two json strings at once , like this :

{"packettype":"1","requestid":"27","packet":{"data":"Some data : 2015-03-06 15:51:30"}}{"packettype":"1","requestid":"28","packet":{"data":"some data : 2015-03-06 15:51:32"}}

how can i parse this into two models ?

Comment: What are you using to parse the string?

Comment: I'd rather solve the original problem and implement a framing protocol, so you can recognize 'messages' your client sends you. Otherwise your next question will be _"How can I prevent parsing half a JSON string and wait until the client sent all of it?"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster My Next Question will never happen because the only problem i have is this . My clients sends the whole packet at once and it is not possible for me to get half of it . and if i got half of it by any chance , i can ignore it . PS , in my test i never got half of packet , but i get a lot of packets together

Comment: CodeCaster is still right. You are not controlling the framing. How can you decide whether a string you received is complete? How can you detect that the string actually contains two distinct json strings?

Comment: What protocol _do_ you use? How does your client send this JSON, and how do you receive it?

Comment: i am using TCP . please just do not advice me not to use Json for send and receive . I know it is not perfect and i must change my protocol , but for the time being i have to use this ... this is phase 1 and there is no tiem for me to change any thing . so please just tell me how to handle this and all my problems are gone . thank you

Comment: @KavehMajidy - you're not listening to CodeCaster or Samuel ... they're not saying to *replace* your JSON solution, just to packetize it. In fact, this is not even a JSON question, but a TCP message framing question. When asked what protocol you used, your reply involved TCP (that's the transport, not the protocol) and JSON (that's the payload). You need to develop an application-level protocol, even if it's just [length-prefix message framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html). P.S. JSON *is* best for payload.